# Form select via Entity always return 0 when save to database

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've a form with select via entity (don't have relation to other table)
but always return 0 when save to database, i can't find error

this is my build form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Company Name'))
            ->add('address')
            ->add('idProvince', 'entity', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => 'SettingBundle:Province',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                       return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
```

select form show perfect with no error, but when i save to database, it always return Zero or null

Whats wrong with my code? do you have a clue or sample for this, 
Thanks

Comment: This code is too poor, we can't understand exactly what's going on here. Please attach every snippet of real code involved otherwise we cannot provide any help.

Comment: hello mr DonCallisto, it solved with entity-relationships-associations, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved with entity-relationships-associations http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

thanks